# How to manipulate the string more efficiently by C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string, foreach

**The Original String**
it is made of 3 parts:

> 1- words (in Chinese)
>  2- [img]pic url[/img]
>  3-
>   [url]url[/url]
>  4- < br>

So the result is something like below:
sometextsometextsometextsometextsometextsometext< br>[img]http://www.a.com/a.jpg[/img]othertextothertextothertextothertextothertext[img]http://c.b.com/a.jpg[/img]anothertextanothertextanothertextanothertextanothertext[url]http://d.e.f[/url]alwaystext[img]http://f.g.com/a.gif[/img][img]http://d.e.net/a.png[/img]

**What I want**
still made of 3 parts, but a little change:

> 1- words 
>  
>   2- < img src="pic url" width="300">
>  
>   3- < a href="url">url < /a> 
>   
>   
>   **What I do now**

```
//content is the source string
string[] contentArray = Regex.Split(content, @"\[img\](.+?)\[/img\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
foreach (string item in contentArray)
{
    //if it is a pic url
    if (item.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &
        (item.EndsWith(".jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
         item.EndsWith(".gif", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
         item.EndsWith(".png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    {
       //convert it into a < img> link
       //append to sb
    }
    else
    {
       string[] contentArray1 = Regex.Split(item, @"\[url\](.+?)\[/url\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
       foreach (string tmpItem in ContentArray)
       {
           if (it is a URL)
           {
              //convert it into a < a> link
              //append to sb
           }
           else //must be normal text
           {
                //to make a better layout
                //put into a < p>
                //append to sb
           }
       }
    }
}
```

**The Problem**
The code above is worked, but, any better solution? to make it more efficiently What I mean "better solution" here means faster speed @_@

Comment: So does your solution work or not?  If not, what about it doesn't work, if it does, what are you hoping to improve?

Comment: @Servy I think it *does* work, but the OP wants to know, if it can't go any faster.

Comment: @Nolonar It's not clear if it works, which is why I asked, and it's also not clear how he wants to improve it, he made no attempt at stating that.  He could want it to run faster, use less memory, be more readable, handle input it currently can't, use less code, or any number of other factors.

Comment: I think the main thing @Servy was pointing out is that "better" is relative. OP - you should clarify what you want to improve.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, I've edited the OP, The code above is worked, but I wonder if there is a better solution to make it more efficiently

Comment: Maybe this is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @AlbertGao And what do you want to make more efficient?  There are a lot of things that can be more or less efficient, and improving one tends to hurt the other.  Is it running too slowly, using too much memory, is it not readable enough, or what?  Additionally, with whatever issue you do have, you need to describe where you're at, and where you need to be.  If it's too slow, how long does it take now, and how quickly does it need to run for you to meet your requirements.

Comment: @Servy I think when somebody optimize code, he never know how many time can save in the last.

Comment: @AlbertGao You should know how long it needs to run in in order to meet your requirements though.  If it runs *fast enough* then there's no need to optimize it further.

Answer (score 0):

One way of coding it is with Match.Replace with MatchEvaluator delegate. Note that there are different indexes when accessing match.Groups items for [url] and [img], because they correspond to different groups in original reg. expression.

```
    public static string ReplaceTags(Match match)
    {
        if (match.Value.StartsWith("[url]") && match.Groups.Count == 4)
            return String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{0}</a>", match.Groups[2]);
        else if (match.Value.StartsWith("[img]") && match.Groups.Count == 4)
            return String.Format("<img src=\"{0}\" width=\"300\">", match.Groups[3]);

        throw new Exception("Unknown match found. Deal with it.");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "text[url]http://some_url[/url]text2[img]http://some/img.jpg[/img]text3";

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\[url](.*)\[/url]|\[img](.*)\[/img])");

        string result = regex.Replace(text, ReplaceTags);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```